# new observers being created when observing lifedata after putting app to background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-lifecycle

I have the following in my viewmodel

```
val currentStockPriceAsLiveData: LiveData<UiState> = stockPriceDataSource.latestStockList
        .map { listOfStock ->
            UiState.Success(listOfStock)
        }.asLiveData()
```

I observe this in my Activity in the onCreate method

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
        
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.currentStockPriceAsLiveData.observe(this@FlowUseCase1Activity) { uiState ->
                if (uiState != null) {
                    if(uiState is UiState.Success) {
                        Timber.d("Received ${uiState.stockList.first()}")
                    }
                    render(uiState)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using repeatOnLifeCycle to only observe when the lifecycle is at least STARTED state. This works as if I put the app in the background it will stop observing.

However, the problem is when I bring the app back to the foreground it will trigger duplicated emissions. And when I put the app to the background a second time it will trigger triple emissions.

From my log:

```
00:00:05.274 23476-23476  D  Received Stock(rank=1, name=Apple, symbol=AAPL, marketCap=2.37819317E12, country=United States, currentPrice=142.95015, currency=DOLLAR, priceTrend=UNKNOWN)
00:00:05.275 23476-23476  D  Received Stock(rank=1, name=Apple, symbol=AAPL, marketCap=2.37819317E12, country=United States, currentPrice=142.95015, currency=DOLLAR, priceTrend=UNKNOWN)
00:00:05.276 23476-23476  D  Received Stock(rank=1, name=Apple, symbol=AAPL, marketCap=2.37819317E12, country=United States, currentPrice=142.95015, currency=DOLLAR, priceTrend=UNKNOWN)
```

As you can see its like its triggering 3 times at the same time.

I think it is because when I put the app to the background the viewmodel has not been destroyed, so when I put the app back in the foreground it creates subsequent observers.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to manage the lifecycle of `LiveData`. `LiveData` manages its own lifecycle. It will pause or resume based on lifecycle of containing `Activity` and `Fragment`.

Use `LiveData` like this in `onCreate()`

```
viewModel.currentStockPriceAsLiveData.observe(this@FlowUseCase1Activity) { uiState ->
            if (uiState != null) {
                if(uiState is UiState.Success) {
                    Timber.d("Received ${uiState.stockList.first()}")
                }
                render(uiState)
            }
        }
```

I don't know exactly why it's duplicating. It may be because you attach a new observer each time the lifecycle reach `STARTED STATE`. `LiveData` does not need to be attached each time the lifecycle changes. It manages its own lifecycle. Call live data as shown above in `onCreate()` just once.